# Install Nuget Package from Network Drive with Cake

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, cakebuild

We have some nuget packages on a network drive that I'd like to be able to reference in my Cake script. The absolute path to the drive looks something like this:

\\MyDrive\NuGet\Packages\mypackage.nupkg

Is there any way to reference this package using preprocessor directives as explained here: http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives#tool-directive

If not, how would I go about doing it without preprocessor directives? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about cake but you can list alternate package sources in a NuGet.config file. So if you can do a nuget restore it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cake pre-processor directive, in addition to the http protocol, also supports the file protocol.  As a result, you can so something like the following

```
#tool nuget:file://localhost/packages/?package=restsharp
```

Comment: Thanks Gary! Worked as expected

Comment: Woot! If you wouldn't mind, could you raise an issue on the website repository (https://github.com/cake-build/website) as I think we should add this into the main docs.

Comment: Sure, no problem